# Sieve of eratosthenes : bit wise optimized

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, optimization, refactoring

After searching the net I came to know that the bit-wise version of the sieve of eratosthenes is pretty efficient.
The problem is I am unable to understand the math/method it is using.

The version that I have been busy with looks like this:

```
#define MAX 100000000
#define LIM 10000

unsigned flag[MAX>>6]={0};

#define ifc(n) (flag[n>>6]&(1<<((n>>1)&31)))         //LINE 1
#define isc(n) (flag[n>>6]|=(1<<((n>>1)&31)))        //LINE 2

void sieve() {
    unsigned i, j, k;
    for(i=3; i<LIM; i+=2)
        if(!ifc(i))
            for(j=i*i, k=i<<1; j<LIM*LIM; j+=k)
                isc(j);
}
```

Points that I understood (Please correct me if I am wrong):

1. Statement in line 1 checks if the number is composite.
2. Statement    in line 2 marks the number 'n' as composite.
3. The program is storing    the value 0 or 1 at a bit of an int. This tends to reduce the memory    usage to x/32. (x is the size that would have been used had an int    been used to store the 0 or 1 instead of a bit like in my solution    above)

Points that are going above my head as of now :

1. How is the finction in LINE 1 functioning.How is the function making sure that the number is composite or not.
2. How is function in LINE 2 setting the bit.
3. I also came to know that the bitwise sieve is timewise efficient as
   well. Is it because of the use of bitwise operators only or
   something else is contributing to it as well.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, there is a bug in the code as well:

unsigned flag[MAX>>6]={0};

divides `MAX` by 64, but if `MAX` is not an exact multiple of 64, the array is one element short.

Line 1: Let's pick it apart:

```
 (flag[n>>6]&(1<<((n>>1)&31)))
```

The `flag[n>>6]` `(n >> 6 = n / 64)` gives the 32-bit integer that holds the bit value for `n / 2`.

Since only "Odd" numbers are possible primes, divide `n` by two: `(n>>1)`.

The `1<<((n>>1)&31)` gives us the bit corresponding to `n/2` within the `0..31` - (`& 31` makes sure that it's "in range").

Finally, use `&` to combine the value on the left with the value on the right.

So, the result is true if element for `n` has  bit number `n modulo 32` set.

The second line is essentially the same concept, just that it uses `|=` (or equal) to set the bit corresponding to the multiple.

Comment: The array is not twice as large as it needs to be: `n >> 6 == n / 64` not `n / 32`.

Comment: Great help!! Thanks. Finally after carefully examining a few cases i got to understand what was happening there.     One last thing. Here you said "Since only "Odd" numbers are possible primes, divide n by two: (n>>1). " but in this line "for(i=3; i<LIM; i+=2)" are we not skipping the even numbers. then why use n>>1.

Comment: Because the table (bitmask) would still need to be twice as big, holding a bunch of ones for all the even numbers. Having twice as large a table will affect performance too.