# Time complexity of an algorithm to find prime numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I was curious about prime numbers and would like to know the most efficient way to find relatively small prime numbers for a range up to say, 10 million. I read that the sieve of erastosthenes (SOE) is the most efficient way to find smaller prime numbers. I implemented SOE using python but had a few questions:

1. The worst case running time of my algorithm seems to be O(n^2). I'm still learning, so I know this algorithm can be made more efficient.
2. Is there a difference in the most efficient mathematical way and most efficient programming way to find prime numbers? Mathematically, SOE is one of the fastest, but programming-wise is SOE all that fast?

   ```
   def FindPrime(n):
       primes = [2, 3]
       for num in range(4, n):
           notprime = False
           for p in primes:
               if num % p == 0:
                   notprime = True
           if notprime == False:
               primes.append(num)

       print primes

   print FindPrime(100)
   ```

Comment: For algo answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers

Comment: But vanilla Python is not efficient at anything big & mathy, period.

Comment: @Jason S - Using Python is completely irrelevant to the *asymptotic* complexity/efficiency of algorithms, except maybe in that it provides a particular set of convenient ready-made building blocks. Assuming you use the same algorithm (with same-algorithm building blocks), Python may well be slower than C or C++, but only by constant factors. A key point about asymptotic analysis (big O etc) is that constant factors are irrelevant.

Comment: The question asked about the difference between math & programming efficiency. If it's really just about the algo it is a dupe.

Comment: @Jason S - good point, but still - efficiency isn't the only factor in language choice.

Comment: People have already answered your question, but I will just point out that the running time of your algorithm is n^2/log n as a consequence of the prime number theorem (the inner loop is order n/log n).

Comment: @TheGreatContini: How did you calculate the inner loop as order n/log n?

Comment: See the prime number theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should know that your algorithm isn't the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). You're using trial division.

There are a number of improvements that can be made to your implementation.

1. Use `xrange()`, which is `O(1)` memory-wise, not `range()`, which is `O(n)`.
2. Skip even numbers in your search: `xrange(4, n, 2)` steps 2 at a time.
3. Don't test if a prime `p` divides `n` when `p > sqrt(n)`. It is not possible.

As you predicted, these changes don't affect the order of complexity, but you'll see a solid performance improvement.

As for a faster algorithm, first implement a real sieve of Eratosthenes, then try the much faster [sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin).

Comment: Great to know. Could you implement the sieve of erastosthenes here in python? Would love to see how it is coded in this language.

Comment: Sieve of Atkins is only much faster than Erasthones version when you are using the optimized code. See http://cr.yp.to/primegen/primegen-0.97.tar.gz for the current version of the source code from the original authors of the improved sieve.

Comment: Read the source that I referenced and you will see optimized code. It is algorithmiically opaque and hard to get right. But it does run fast. Suggesting writing the Atkin version is a waste of time for a newbie question; esp. in python. Python is great for a lot of things, all-purpose speed is not one of those things, even with PyPy, Psyco and Pyrex, etc.

Comment: Sending a newbie to write C++ is wasting his time. This is learning.

Answer (score 0):

1. uʍop ǝpısdn is right your code is not SOE
2. you can find mine SOE implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25142188/2521214)

   - **which makes the prime finding more efficient then yours solution**
3. complexity of mine implementation of SOE

   - time: `T(0.5·n·DIGAMMA(CEIL(SQRT(n))+0.3511·n)` if the sqrt(N) is used like suggested in comment inside code
   - time(n=   1M): `T(3.80*n)`
   - time(n=  10M): `T(4.38*n)`
   - time(n= 100M): `T(4.95*n)`
   - time(n=1000M): `T(5.53*n)`
   - so approximately the run time is: `T((0.3516+0.5756*log10(n))*n)`
   - so the complexity is `O(n.log(n))`
4. difference between speed (runtime) and complexity O()

   - the actual runtime is `t=T(f(n))*c`
   - for big enough n it converges to `t=O(f(n))*c`
   - where `O()` is the time complexity of algorithm
   - and `T()` is actual run time equation for any n (not `O()` !!!)
   - the `c` is some constant time which is needed to process single pass in all `for`s together etc...
   - better `O()` does not mean faster solution
   - for any `n` only after treshold where
   - `O1(f1(n))*c1 < O2(f2(n))*c2`
   - so if you well optimize the `c` constant then you can beat better complexity algorithms up to a treshold
   - for example your code is around `T(n.n/2)` -> `O(n^2)`
   - but for low n can be faster then mine SOE `O(n.log(n))`
   - because mine needs to prepare tables which takes more time then your divison up to a point
   - but after that yours get much much slower ...

**So for the question if there is difference between most efficient math and programing solution**

- the answer is **YES** it can be **on defined N-range**